# Make search bar functional

Tags: php, html, search

```
<div id="search">
<form method="post" action="sphider/search.php">
<fieldset>
<input type="text" name="s" id="search-text"  title="Search our website" size="15" value="" />
<input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="GO" />
                </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

I have almost fixed this code, just wondering how I can get it to work using the current toolbar instead of opening the php script file.

Comment: Read more about `LIKE` operators in SQL.

Comment: The "action" attribute tells what script to send your data to.  Unless you have it handled in JavaScript, this is going nowhere.

Comment: @Gary this will do a get request on the same page.

Comment: Yes, the request needs to be handled somehow in the serverside _perhaps in php_, to have the functionality working.

Comment: It looks like a wordpress search form, if you bought a wordpress theme, just use it. The search functionality is built in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need some server-sided script to actually search the given query. From the [W3C HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html):

> A form is a component of a Web page that has form controls, such as
>   text fields, buttons, checkboxes, range controls, or color pickers. A
>   user can interact with such a form, providing data **that can then be
>   sent to the server for further processing** (e.g. returning the results
>   of a search or calculation).

In general, besides a scripting language (such as PHP), your server will need a database management system - e.g., MySQL - in order to store and handle your data efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

**You may try this design...**

```
#search {

}

#search input{
    background: url(search-dark.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #444;
    border: 0 none;
    font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    color: #777;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
    }

#search input[type="text"]:focus {
    outline: none;
    background: url(search-white.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #444;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0px white;
    color: red;
    }

<form method="get" action="/search" id="search">
  <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..." />
</form>
```